# Is energy density of two $P$ W lamps the same for one $2P$ W lamp?

Tags: visible-light, power

Do two lamps of power $P$ produce the same energy output as single lamp of power $2P$, assuming ideal environment? E.g. lamps do not occlude each other, distance between lamps is negligible, no monochromatic interference, same input energy to output energy ratio.

In my basic understanding it should be the same, and adding more lamps (or increasing their power) should scale energy output linearly, but something makes me unsure about that (I'm possibly wrongly thinking about *perceived brightness*, which is nonlinear).

Comment: Just to be clear: by power _P_, do you mean electrical power or radiant power (flux)?  And by 'energy output' do you mean radiant power (flux)?  The conversion of electrical power to radiant flux is not necessarily linear, especially for different lamps.  If by _P_ you did mean radiant flux, then yes, it's the same, but it's a tautology:  x + x = 2x.

Comment: I have meant radiant power - assuming abstract lamps without any declared power intake.

Comment: @SeanSkelly if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Sorry for an extremely basic question.

Comment: No worries - just checking for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radiant flux does add linearly - two lamps with radiant flux P will sum to a total flux of *2P* and match the single lamp with *2P*.

With lamps, we should all be careful to separate electrical power from radiant power.  Different lamps will have a different conversion rate of electrical power to radiant power (especially in the visible wavelengths - many lamps produce heat). Two lamps of the same electrical power may not produce the same radiant power output as one lamp of twice the electrical power.